# Function parameters: accepting a null value also

Tags: c++, methods, parameters, arguments

Hi guys I'm currently writing a function that changes the colors of my borders.

`void ChangeColor(D3DXVECTOR4 xColorLeft, D3DXVECTOR4 xColorRight, D3DXVECTOR4 xColorTop, D3DXVECTOR4 xColorBot);`

Now this is all fine, however I want to give my user some ease of use, such as if `ChangeColor` is called with a NULL value, it won't change anything.

Example:

`ChangeColor(D3DXVECTOR4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), NULL, NULL, NULL);`

With this function call I would change the color of my left border, but since NULL is called on the other borders I would leave them to their default values. When I try this call I get some error about overloaded method containing `ints`.

Is this possible without making any methods such as `ChangeColorLeft` etc? If so how would I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try default parameters?

Comment: What do you mean by default parameters?

Comment: Advantage with `ChangeColorLeft` is that the intention is clear, else you have to remember the order (and no order is perfect/intuitive))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happily, a D3DXVECTOR4 is a set of four floats, and floats support magic values like NAN.  So how about this:

```
const D3DXVECTOR4 NoColor(NAN, NAN, NAN, NAN);
void ChangeColor(
    D3DXVECTOR4 xColorLeft = NoColor,
    D3DXVECTOR4 xColorRight = NoColor,
    D3DXVECTOR4 xColorTop = NoColor,
    D3DXVECTOR4 xColorBot = NoColor);
```

Then you just check inside if each argument is NAN, and if so, don't change that one.

Comment: This is a great idea. To clarify, I guess I'll have to make `NoColor` a constant like how `NULL` and `NAN` are?

Comment: @user2280704: Yes, it should be const--I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with your `NULL` value...
but I don't find that clean (the special default colour value is better):

```
void changeColorLeft(void*) { /* Do nothing */ }
void changeColorRight(void*) { /* Do nothing */ }
void changeColorTop(void*) { /* Do nothing */ }
void changeColorBottom(void*) { /* Do nothing */ }

void changeColorLeft(const D3DXVECTOR4& color) { /* implementation */ }
void changeColorRight(const D3DXVECTOR4& color) { /* implementation */ }
void changeColorTop(const D3DXVECTOR4&) color{ /* implementation */ }
void changeColorBottom(const D3DXVECTOR4& color) { /* implementation */ }

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
void ChangeColor(T1&& xColorLeft, T2&& xColorRight, T3&& xColorTop, T4&& xColorBot)
{
    changeColorLeft(xColorLeft);
    changeColorRight(xColorRight);
    changeColorTop(xColorTop);
    changeColorBottom(xColorBot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no conversion between NULL and D3DXVECTOR4. You could use pointers to D3DXVECTOR4 as arguments, they can be NULL.